# Identify unusual thin bicycle frame

Tags: frames

What is the generic name and/or specific products associated with the illustrated frame? Is it lighter than a normal frame?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a [Moulton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulton_Bicycle) (Wikipedia).

Specifically, it could be the APB model from the early 90s, or the current TSR with optional rear rack.  I can't tell from the photos.

Their "space frame" design has those unusual extra tubes, as well as lighter tubes. The long integrated rear rack is also distinctive.

Comment: They're quite distinctive and rather desirable, so pro bike thieves will target these just as much as a nice modern bike.   Moulteesers should definitely take their bikes inside where possible.

Comment: @Criggie some of them are nice modern bikes - the current TSR comes with 2×11 gearing

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction! On Wikipedia, this model photo looks quite similar to the question: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Spacey_Moulton_Folder_Maine_Monument_jeh.jpg